# What's the best way to end a C++ program Launched with ShellExecute function?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

What's the best way to end a c++ program launched with ShellExecute function from the main program?. like..

```
 ShellExecute(hwnd, TEXT("open"), TEXT("c:\\tools\\123\\myProgram.exe"),
              TEXT(""), NULL, 0);
```

In this case the launched program is "my Program.exe" and i want to end them. Both the main program & the launched program console application written in vc++.

Comment: You might be better off using `CreateProcess` and holding onto the handle to use with `TerminateProcess`.

Comment: Compromise: use ShellExecuteEx, which is still pretty similar to ShellExecute, but gives you a handle to the process you start (which you can then use with TerminateProcess to kill that process).

Comment: @JerryCoffin, Even easier. I can't recall ever needing a handle where I didn't need the customizability of `CreateProcess` :p

Comment: @chris & Jerry which are better using ShellExecute or ShellExecuteEx or CreateProcess to launching a program? as i want only to launching aprogram and after rand time i want to end it. thanks.

Comment: @abdo.eng2006210, `CreateProcess` has a lot more that you can specify, such as which desktop to create the process on. `ShellExecute` is more like clicking it in explorer, and is shorter to use when you don't need the extra stuff `CreateProcess` offers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sub-program:

```
int main(/*...*/) {
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

You could tell it to do this from the main program through inter-process communication or by sending a control sequence of some kind to the sub-program's `stdin`.  Posting `WM_QUIT` or `WM_CLOSE` to the other process should also work if it has a message pump.

`TerminateProcess()` will end the program, but it's certainly not the best way.  (cleanup isn't run)

`Exit(0)` isn't a bad way to go either, but it also requires the sub-program to be told it should terminate.

Comment: If you've got an open handle to the sub-program's `stdin`, the usual solution is to close that handle. The sub-program will then exit once it hits EOF on `stdin`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is a normal exit from sub process (return). It's always better than trying to terminate process from another one because you never can know in what state the sub process is. You can use kernel object like event, or even create a file in order to be seen by sub process. This should signal it to exit.

Answer (score 1):

You will be much better off spawning process using CreateProcess. You can use process ID to terminate spawned process gracefully:

In the child process, register ctrl handler by calling SetConsoleCtrlHandler.
In the handlet handle CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT.

When you are ready to terminate the child process, call EnumWindows passing process ID obtained from PROCESS_INFORMATION structure you passed to CreateProcess as LPARAM.

In enumerate windows procedure call GetWindowThreadProcessId and compare with LPARAM you passed and if they match, call PostMessage or SendMessage, passing windows handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND message, SC_CLOSE command as WPARAM and 0 as LPARAM;

Your child process will receive CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT control type. In a handler, before returning call a function that will perform cleanup and exit. After that return TRUE from the handler.